# Using `os.path.exists` when the folder name has a space in it?

Tags: python, linux

hello i am using the following code but it is not worked .
this is the part of my code.
value of `useris` and `folder2` variable comes randomly from my application.

but this code goes only into else condition. this directories are exists.

```
useris = "user"
folder2 = "/'Personal Files'/Docs"
if os.path.exists("/usr/bin/.%s/c_drive%s/test.exe"%(useris,folder2)):
    print "folder exists"
else:
    print "folder not exists"
```

suggest the solution.

Comment: Add a `print("/usr/bin/ [...] %(useris,folder2))` and you will see your mistake.

Comment: could be because of the dot here: ``/.%s/``

Comment: @mpf82 but this is the hidden folder thats why it is .%s.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `Personal Files`.

Comment: silly question - does the folder `Personal Files` actually contain quotation marks? because you generally only use quotation marks if you're typing something at the command line to prevent the parser from splitting it inappropriately.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ but i am running this code in ubuntu Linux. not in windows

Comment: @Petesh not it is not actually contain quotation marks

Comment: @PurvalPatel Either way, you don't use quote marks to escape spaces. os.path will still work.

Comment: yeah its working .after removing quotation marks..thank you

Comment: @PurvalPatel Added an answer for posterity. Please consider marking it accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around `Personal Files`. The quotation marks are only for the shell to interpret and understand, but `os.path` can understand and parse spaces without them.

So, if I were to have a folder called "Made in Abyss" on my Desktop, this is what I'd do:

```
In [858]: os.path.exists('/Users/coldspeed/Desktop/Made in Abyss')
Out[858]: True
```

So, in your case, this should work:

```
useris = "user"
folder2 = "/Personal Files/Docs"
```